AVR program(for ATmega328p) restarts after interrupts (Proteus 8)
The program is written in C and compiled for AVR microcontroller ATmega328p. The program is being debugged in Proteus 8. After all interrupts are executed, the program restarts from the initialization section instead of entering the main loop. The program is expected to enter an infinite loop in the main function after initialization.
Could someone point out what the problem might be and what to look for?
P.S. It happens not all the time, but often.
main.c
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "lic328p_gpio.h"
#include "lic_menuio.h"
#include "battery.h"
#include "lic_18650h.h"
#include "lic_uart.h"
#include "lic_adc.h"

static volatile tx_data tx_package;
static volatile adc_channel channel;
static volatile batlist batstat;

ISR(ADC_vect) {

  uint16_t data = adc();
  batt_data_handling(data, &batstat);
  fill_tx_package(&batstat, &tx_package);
  UCSR0B |= (1 << UDRIE0);      
}

ISR(USART_RX_vect) {

  setMode(&menu, UDR0);                 // Selecting the Menu Mode
}

ISR(USART_UDRE_vect) {

    if(tx_package.index < tx_package.length) {
        UDR0 = tx_package.data[tx_package.index];
        tx_package.index++;
    } else {
        tx_package.inprocess = false;
        UCSR0B &= ~(1 << UDRIE0);
    };
}

ISR(USART_TX_vect) {

}

int main(void) {

  port_init();
  uart_init(MYUBRR);
  timer_init();
  adc_init();

  init_adcChan(&channel);
  init_battData(&batstat);
  init_tx_data(&tx_package);

  sei();

  while(1) {
  };

  return 0;
}



The program is incomplete. We don't see what all used types and invoked functions are. Also fuse bytes. Do you have watchdog enabled?

I have added a picture of the fuses settings in Proteus to the question description. The WatchDog is unprogrammed. As for the rest of the library files that describe all the data types and functions, I would be happy to show them, but there are many of them and I thought it would be inappropriate to post them here.

In timer_init() you enable timer overflow interrupt but no handler defined. I don't know what toolchain you use, but avr-gcc in this case jumps to _bad_interruptwhich jumps to reset vector.

I have added a link to my project's GitHub repository in the description.

Yes, i looked into that code and pointed in previous comment to at least one issue with timer overflow interrupt, which may cause jump to reset vector.
Side note: don't change bit fields in registers one-by-one, set them at once. For example, instead of ADCSRA |= (1<<ADPS0); ADCSRA |= (1<<ADPS1); ADCSRA &= (1<<ADPS2) write ADCSRA = (ADCSRA | (1<<ADPS0) | (1<<ADPS1)) & ~(1<<ADPS2); Or uint8_t tmp = ADCSRA; tmp |= ...; tmp &= ...; ADCSRA = tmp;

@dimich Thank you so much! Your comment about the enabled timer counter interrupt on overflow without a handler was indeed the main problem with the microcontroller reset. I checked everything and now I can continue working on my project =). It would be nice if you could write an answer to my question so that I could mark it as a solution and you could get a rating, if of course you need it.

Please do not link to external resources, as these tend to vanish. Please [edit] your question to add a [mre].

The main purpose of answers and their acceptance is not the reputation, this just adds to our motivation. The main purpose is to build a knowledge base for others, now and in the future. That's why it is so important to write self-contained questions. This is not a forum.

@thebusybee I have removed the link to GitHub from the description. I am grateful to everyone who takes the time to help.
